# Beautiful soup: Extract text and urls from a list, but only under specific headings

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am looking to use Beautiful Soup to scrape the Fujitsu news update page: https://www.fujitsu.com/uk/news/pr/2020/

I only want to extract the information under the headings of the current month and previous month.

For a particular month (e.g. November), I am trying to extract into a list

- the Title
- the URL
- the text

for each news briefing (so a list of lists).

My attempt so far is as follow (showing only previous month for simplicity):

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
year_str = str(today.year) 

current_m = today.month
previous_m = current_m - 1
current_m_str = calendar.month_name[current_m]
previous_m_str = calendar.month_name[previous_m]

URL = 'https://www.fujitsu.com/uk/news/pr/' + year_str + '/'
resp = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')

previous_m_body = soup.find('h3', text=previous_m_str)
if previous_m_body is not None:
    for sib in previous_m_body.find_next_siblings():
        if sib.name == "h3":
            break
        else:
            previous_m_text = str(sib.text)
            print(previous_m_text)
```

However, this generates one long string with newlines, and no separation between Title, text, url:

Fujitsu signs major contract with Scottish Government to deliver election e-Counting solution London, United Kingdom, November 30, 2020 - Fujitsu, a leading digital transformation company, has today announced a major contract with the Scottish Government and Scottish Local...

Fujitsu Introduces Ultra-Compact, 50A PCB Relay for Medium-to-Heavy Automotive Loads Hoofddorp, EMEA, November 11, 2020 - Fujitsu Components Europe has expanded its automotive relay offering with a new 12VDC PCB relay featuring.......

I have attached an image of the page DOM.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = requests.get("https://www.fujitsu.com/uk/news/pr/2020/").text
all_lists = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find_all("ul", class_="filterlist")

news = []
for unordered_list in all_lists:
    for list_item in unordered_list.find_all("li"):
        news.append(
            [
                list_item.find("a").getText(),
                f"https://www.fujitsu.com{list_item.find('a')['href']}",
                list_item.getText(strip=True)[len(list_item.find("a").getText()):],
            ]
        )

for news_item in news:
    print("\n".join(news_item))
    print("-" * 80)
```

Output (shortened for brevity):

```
Fujitsu signs major contract with Scottish Government to deliver election e-Counting solution
https://www.fujitsu.com/uk/news/pr/2020/fs-20201130.html
London, United Kingdom, November 30, 2020- Fujitsu, a leading digital transformation company, has today announced a major contract with the Scottish Government and Scottish Local Authorities to support the electronic counting (e-Counting) of ballot papers at the Scottish Local Government elections in May 2022.Fujitsu Introduces Ultra-Compact, 50A PCB Relay for Medium-to-Heavy Automotive LoadsHoofddorp, EMEA, November 11, 2020- Fujitsu Components Europe has expanded its automotive relay offering with a new 12VDC PCB relay featuring a switching capacity of 50A at 14VDC. The FBR53-HC offers a higher contact rating than its 40A FBR53-HW counterpart, yet occupies the same 12.1 x 15.5 x 13.7mm footprint and weighs the same 6g.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

and more ...
```

EDIT:

To get just the last two months, all you need is the first two `ul` items from the `soup`. So, add `[:2]` to the first `for loop`, like this:

```
for unordered_list in all_lists[:2]:
    # the rest of the loop body goes here
```

Comment: Hi - many thanks for the reponse.

This seems to work, but only for the first news item in each month (all the way back to Jan 2020) How could I amend this to extract all of the news items for the current and previous month?

Comment: I think this is because while the 'soup' contains 10 ul items (10 different months), these each contain 1 or more news items but the for loop is only extracting the first instance of 'a', href and the summary text?

Answer (score -1):

here I modified your code. I combined your bs4 code with selenium. Selenium is very powerful for scrape dynamic or JavaScript based website. You can use selenium with BeautifulSoup for make your life easier. Now it will give you output for all months.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    
    
    driver =  webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.maximize_window()
    
    url = "https://www.fujitsu.com/uk/news/pr/2020/" #change the url if you want to get result for different year
    
    driver.get(url)
    
   # now your bs4 code start. It will give you output from current month to previous all month
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser") 
    
    #here I am getting all month name from January to november.  
    months = soup.find_all('h3')
    
    for month in months:
            month = month.text
            print(f"month_name : {month}\n")
    #here we are getting all description text from current month to all previous months 
    description_texts = soup.find_all('ul',class_='filterlist')
    for description_text in description_texts:
        description_texts = description_text.text.replace('\n','')
        print(f"description_text: {description_texts}")
```

**output:**
[image]

Comment: Using `selenium` in this case is just a pure overkill.